# Fade between multiple SKTextures, SKSpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Happy New Year! I am trying to fade in multiple SKTextures using a sequence SKAction but I'm not exactly sure how to do so. The way I currently have it has no effect during the change between textures, and that is what I am looking for if it is possible. Thanks

```
var playButtonAnimation: SKAction
var playButtonFadeIn: SKAction
var playButtonFadeOut: SKAction
var playButtonTextures:[SKTexture] = []
 for i in 1...7 {
       playButtonTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "button\(i)"))
 }
playButtonAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: playButtonTextures, timePerFrame: 3.0)
playButtonFadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 1.0)
playButtonFadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)
playButton.zPosition = -25
playButton.run(SKAction.sequence([playButtonFadeIn,playButtonAnimation,playButtonFadeOut]))
playButton.run(SKAction.repeatForever(playButtonAnimation))
addChild(playButton)
```

Comment: The effect you want is not clear. To have an animated sequence where each frame fades in and then fades out and then that is repeated for subsequent frames?  To have the sequence animating and meanwhile the sprite should fade in, wait a while, and then fade out?  Something else?  In general you probably don't want to have one sprite running two actions that are both doing `animate(with:timePerFrame:)`.  They'll be interfering with each other in trying to change the texture.

Comment: Sort of, Im trying to get each frame to fade into the next. I tried FadeIn and FadeOut but they were not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You mean like a video cross fade (or dissolve I think it's sometimes called) sort of thing?

Comment: have you ever seen those light strips that fade between colors? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLawm_ve9dM < -- Here is an example. I'm trying to do that with colors literally but i have them as SKTextures

Comment: If you want to fade between textures, you'd probably have to have two sprite nodes with alternately changing alphas, since texture switches are discrete actions.  That's doable, though I'm not sure how it would look.  Another option if it's just colors though is to have an uncolored (grayscale) texture for the sprite's shape, and then give it color via the `color` and `colorBlendFactor` properties.  Those properties can be animated over a duration with the `colorize` actions.

Comment: You want to use group,  have you fading in and out be 1 sequence (be sure to add a delay in the middle), and use `SKAction.group` to group it with your animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want to use the SKAction.group action to get what you need done.

Currently what this code will do is fade in and out per texture:

```
var playButtonAnimation: SKAction
var playButtonFadeIn: SKAction
var playButtonFadeOut: SKAction
var playButtonTextures:[SKTexture] = []
 for i in 1...7 {
       playButtonTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "button\(i)"))
 }
playButtonAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: playButtonTextures, timePerFrame: 3.0)
playButtonFadeIn = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 1.0)
playButtonFadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)
let seq = SKAction.sequence([playButtonFadeIn,SKAction.wait(forDuration:1.0),playButtonFadeOut])
let grp = SKAction.group([SKAction.repeat(seq,count:7),playButtonAnimation])

playButton.zPosition = -25
playButton.run(SKAction.repeatForever(grp))
addChild(playButton)
```

Comment: If I understood him, he doesn't want it to fade out and then come back with a new texture.  Rather he's looking to have two textures shown at the same time, with one gradually fading in while the other is fading out, like a fairly common video transition.  He linked to a youtube video above showing some LEDs doing what he wants. AFAICT, it's not possible to do the equivalent of a cross-fade while having only one sprite node (barring the colorizing I mentioned above for the special case of only color changes).

Comment: Yeah I saw the video, wasnt sure how that correlated with his textures or his question, but I will add cross fading

Comment: Now that I think about it some more, maybe a cross fade would be possible for one sprite with a custom shader, but if there's a way to do gradual transitions between textures on one sprite without that, I'd like to learn about it.

Comment: Ah, SKUniforms can indeed be texture references.  That's useful info.  Not SKAttributes unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your efforts. So I've tried the code posted above and it works for the first image, but then stops afterwards. Is there anyway I could have the same effect but for multiple textures in the playButtonTextures Array?

Comment: put the sequence in a repeat

Comment: Cross dissolving is a little more complex.  Outside of a shader, you would need to use two SKNodes with alternating frames.  Since you already said this works for you, I am not going to attempt that type of complexity.